# Listening for button click in PWA service worker

Tags: javascript, dom, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to follow the following example for PWA Push Notifications but have a general question regarding service workers

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/

Within my Service Worker, I want to add a listener to a button/anchor tag

My Service Worker is initialised as follows:

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator && "PushManager" in window) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
        .register("./scripts/my.serviceworker.js", { scope: "/" })
        .then(function (swReg) {
            console.log("Service Worker Registered: ", swReg);
            swRegistration = swReg;
            initializeUI();
        });
};
```

And the function initializeUI() needs to contain a listener for the click event so that the user can subscribe/unsubscribe

```
function initializeUI() {
    var pushButton = document.querySelector(".pwa-pushbutton");
    pushButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("Button pushed");
        if (isSubscribed) {
            // TODO: Unsubscribe user
        } else {
            subscribeUser();
        }
    });
```

But the pushButton variable is not defined.

How can I add a listener event to an element on the DOM within my service worker JS file?

Comment: Hmm.. actually this code should work. As I understood your code initializeUI() is not in your serviceworker.js file and therefore should have access to the dom.

Answer (score 5):

Service Workers cannot listen to nor interact with DOM directly.  All DOM activity (like clicks) would need to be sent to Service Workers with `postMessage()`

#### App:

```
function onClick(event => {
  navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({
    value1: 'hello',
    value2: 'there'
  });
})
```

#### Service Worker:

```
self.addEventListener('message', event => { 
  const val1 = event.data.value1,
        val2 = event.data.value2;
});
```

Comment: Nice, thanks ; What about the other way around: Send an event from the Service Worker to the App?

Comment: Consider [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage) or [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel).  see [Jake Archibald's examples](https://gist.github.com/jakearchibald/a1ca502713f41dfb77172be4523a9a4c)